# what is multilevel relationship query? can any one explain

Tags: apex

```
SELECT Id, SystemModstamp, Product__r.Catalog__r.Active__c 
FROM Journal__c
```

Can any one explain the concept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the given query...

You are writing a SOQL query on the object Journal__c. In this query you are fetching the value of a field from the parent of the parent of the object you are querying on (Journal__c). In this case You want the value of a field in the Catalog__c object which is the grandparent of the current object you are querying on.
Since this query fetches field values from multiple objects related by a hierarchy this is called a multilevel query.

See documentation such as [A Deeper look at SOQL and Relationship Queries on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com).